# Update DynamoDB without activating trigger

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my serverless backend I have a DynamoDB table collecting data. 
A Lambda function is attached to the DynamoDB with a trigger - when the table is updated the trigger fires the Lambda function.

**Problem:** The Lambda functions performs an [Update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property) on the same row, thus triggering the Lambda function again (and again and again...)

**Question:** Is there any way to perform a DynamoDB update *without* enabling the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda function should be checking for something, perhaps a new field it needs to add to any records it updates, so that when it is triggered again it will know it was triggered by its own update and it doesn't need to update the record again.

Comment: I was hoping to find a more elegant solution. It's a waste of money to execute a unnecessary Lambda function (if its possible to avoid)

Comment: Also, In my case "something" does not exists. There is no way to determine if last update was performed by the Lambda function or a third party system.

Comment: I agree it seems unnecessary, however it is not possible to have DynamoDB conditionally trigger the Lambda function. It will trigger the function on every update. Do you have any control over what specific updates the third party system makes, like can you add an extra field for it to update?

Comment: @Vingtoft while you may not be able to control the 3p system you can definitely control the lambda so in the worst case scenario you can break the cycle after one update from your lambda.